# What wishes have been made upon the Triforce?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series

The myth of the triforce says that anybody who touches the Triforce can see any of their wishes made real.

Ganon tries often to take it for himself to wish ultimate power, ruling the world, and other bad guy things.

But has the triforce ever granted a wish. To who, and what did they wish for?

Comment: There is at least one instance of this in The Wind Waker, where King Hyrule asks the gods of the Triforce to wash away the kingdom of Hyrule, so that Link and Zelda may have hope for a future: [as seen here](https://youtu.be/L9x9zTyN1QU?t=3m33s). This is the only instance I can come up with off the top of my head, but I'll look further into it later today.

Comment: Does Ganondorf use the Triforce when Link is sealed in the Temple of Time in Ocarina (to gain power, plunge the land into darkness, and scatter the sages)? Or did ge do that through other means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **A Link to the Past**, Link defeats Ganon and is able to take the Triforce for himself. His wish is that the effect of Ganon's evil actions are reversed, thus restoring Hyrule (the and Sacred Land) to its former glory.

In **Wind Waker**, during the final showdown, Ganondorf is moments away from touching the Triforce, but the King of Hyrule beats him to it. The King wishes that the old land of Hyrule is submerged forever under the waves of the Great Sea, and that Link and Tetra can lives their lives in the new world above the ocean. As the wish is granted, Ganondorf is thrown into a fit of rage and attacks Link. However, Link is able to counterattack and deals the final blow to his archnemesis, killing Ganondorf for the last time (in that particular timeline, anyway).

In **Skyward Sword**, Link is able to combine the Triforce as well. His wish is the destruction of Demise. As a result, the Goddess Statue on Skyloft breaks free and falls to earth, crushing the villain's seal and killing him. Unfortunately his servant, Ghirahim, kidnaps Zelda immediately after and travels back in time to when his master was still alive. He uses Zelda in a ritual that  unseals Demise, thus subverting Link's wish.

Comment: Does Ganondorf use the Triforce when Link is sealed in the Temple of Time in Ocarina (to gain power, plunge the land into darkness, and scatter the sages)? Or did ge do that through other means?

Comment: @cpimhoff He might have used the power f the triforce, but we aren't ever told if that was an actual wish.

Comment: @cpimhoff I'm not 100% sure, since it's been a while, but I think do not think he was able to make a wish when Link was sealed away. When he touched the Triforce at that time, it split apart (on its own) because he did not have a balance of power, wisdom, and courage. He had mostly power, and thus became the "owner" of the Triforce of Power. The Triforce of Wisdom went to Zelda (which is why he's looking for her and why she needs to stay disguised as Sheik) and the Triforce of Courage goes to Link. Only if Ganondorf reunites all pieces again can he make a wish - and he never did, in that game.

Answer (score 3):

In a Link Between Worlds, Zelda and Link make a wish on the Triforce to restore Lorule's destroyed Triforce.